# Get list of all on screen UI elements

Tags: android

It is possible to get a list of all the currently displayed/on-screen android UI elements?

For example, if I have a app that look like this:

[image: EZ android app]

I would get a list that would contain:

- TextView (Hello World!)
- RelativeLayout (Or whatever the parent container is)
- Etc if there were more elements

This would be great in the case I don't know the ID's, or even what UI elements will appear on screen, but I still want to hide/show them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### You can achieve this by using the following manager, nice and clean!

Use it anywhere you want and you'll get a list of the view and all its children.

*(Needs to be done recursively)*

---

> LayoutManager.*getViews*(getWindow());

---

```
public class LayoutManager
{
    private static List<View> views;

    public static List<View> getViews(Window window) {
        return getViews(window.getDecorView().getRootView(), true);
    }

    public static List<View> getViews(final View view, boolean starting)
    {
        if (starting) {
            views = new ArrayList<>();
        }

        views.add(view);

        /** Search in each ViewGroup children as well */
        if (view instanceof ViewGroup) {
            ViewGroup viewGroup = (ViewGroup) view;
            for (int i = 0; i < viewGroup.getChildCount(); i++) {
                getViews(viewGroup.getChildAt(i), false);
            }
        }

        return views;
    }
}
```